# Unable to hit Web Api in .Net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

Hi I am just starting to mess with WebApi to setup a REST api for my angular app.

I simply just added a "Web API 2 Controller with read/write actions"

I then just try to test it by just typing the url in the browser but I get a 404.

Everything is pretty much out of the box.

WebApiConfig.cs looks like

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

RouteConfig.cs is

```
    public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Global.asax

```
        protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

        InitializeDatabase("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=msproto;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;");
    }
```

Is there something I have to add to the web config? If I add a normal controller "MVC 5 Controller with read/write actions" it will hit my breakpoints in the get requests.

Comment: What order are they being executed in the global.asax? Web API routes first or MVC routes first?

Comment: oh.. i actually dont even see the webapi config being called at all. How do I register that?(sorry im a js developer!)

Comment: I updated my post and added the global asax, I added GlobalConfiguration... but still not working

Comment: nm I took your comment and assumed I should probably move it to the top. looks like its working now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the Web API routes are registered *before* the MVC routes in your Global.asax.